# How to fix "TypeError: Cannot read property 'inherits' of undefined" in React project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I working on React project. I'm trying to use the npm package `async-polling` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-polling), that wants to use the `inherits` class of the `node-utils` ; Internally the library has the following lines:

```
var inherits = hasWindow ? window.nodeUtil.inherits : require('util').inherits;
var EventEmitter = hasWindow ? window.nodeEventEmitter : require('events').EventEmitter;
```

Of course since the app is running in the browser, `hasWindow` is true. But there is no `nodeUtil` or `nodeEventEmitter`. Therefore I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'inherits' of undefined
```

Then I tried adding the `util` and `events` package and doing this:

```
window.nodeUtil = require('util');
window.nodeEventEmitter = require('events');
```

But I got this error:

```
TypeError: AsyncPolling is not a constructor
```

Anther fork was able to fix this issue, but I want to try and stick with the original package, is there a way to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As best I can tell `async-polling` is an old, unmaintained module that you're better off avoiding. You're running into problems because the module is expecting the presence of two global variables `nodeUtil` and `nodeEventEmitter`. It looks like the package is better suited to a node environment and is relying on polyfills in the browser.

I'd suggest finding a more up-to-date package or simply using `setInterval` to poll.

```
const intervalInMilliseconds = 5000;
const timerId = setInterval(() => {
  if (/* some condition is met */) {
    clearInterval(timerId);
  } else {
    // do stuff
  }
}, intervalInMilliseconds);
```